# How to create Interactive Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to create Interactive Reports using a tool.
Currently I work with Jasper reports. But it allows me to create only read only reports.
I want to create a user interactive report. For example, if the report takes a date range input parameters, the user should be able to modify the input on report on say, some button click event on the report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the input control functionality built into JasperReports Server. It has had the ability to do the date range sample that you mention for many years. Interactive sorting and filtering are more recent, but they are there too.

Comment: Absolutely, Using input controls did help. Here I am pasting the link that helped me for a reference. http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=47240

Answer (score 5):

Other than the solution of @mdahlman you could use a different approach. Depending on what you want to do:

If you want to have a defined frontend for your users where they can tune exactly as much as you want them to -> Write a frontend in Java that calls JasperReports below.

If you have Users that are Techs themselves and are comfortable with complex Frontends give them IReport.

You could also generate a fine result in Pentaho (which has nothing to do with Jasper Reports) and if it fits your need is nice.

All in all your question is very vague and many answers apply.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Thank you so much your answer lit my bulb. :)

Comment: @SaharHassan Please consider marking one of the answers as correct then. (The hook under the vote elements left of an answer)